# The Regularization Path for Smoothing Splines

Tags: r, optimization, regularization, ridge-regression, splines

I've got a potentially interesting question. Does anyone know if R already has a package for calculating the entire regularization path of the smoothing spline?

That is, for: 
$$\hat{f}_{\lambda}=argmin\|y-f\|^{2}+\lambda\int(f''(x))^2dx$$
Does R have a function that will calculate the path $\{\hat{f}_{\lambda},\forall \lambda \ge0 \}$ much like glmnet for the elastic net or svmpath for svms?

The problem is "solved" in the general sense in that [Rosset, Zhu (2007)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjXyMfWkurPAhUJbT4KHacUDFIQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Feuclid.aos%2F1185303996&usg=AFQjCNG_53N570mpaYLU3Rj00p6uO4fZDg&sig2=WRFnOd0nWC2hEOazsAepyA&bvm=bv.136499718,d.cWw) gave general conditions under which we can find that path. They even give the full algorithm for the locally adaptive regression splines (which is the same as above with a TV penalty instead) but nothing for the cubic spline.

I was told that GCV analytically finds the regularization path but as far as I can tell, GCV analytically finds the error as a function of the regularization parameter which, instead of giving us the full path, is useful for choosing the "best" (loaded word) value of $\lambda$.

Any word on whether there's a solver for this sort of problem?

Comment: The [gamsel package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamsel/index.html) talks about fitting the "entire regularization path" both in the [arxiv preprint article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03850v2.pdf) and the [manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamsel/gamsel.pdf)

Comment: I actually ran into the gamsel package but I'm not entirely sure I can write the spline objective as the objective function they specify. It also specifies a particular basis. It does look interesting though. Have you been able to get it to compile?